# R converting a date (dd/mm/yy) to (mm/yy)

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (`df`)  with a date column Date (`dd-mm-yyyy`).
How do I convert it to just (`mm-yyyy`)?

I have tried:

```
dates <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%Y")
```

but this did not work. I would be greatful for your help.

Comment: Do you want yyyy or yy?  Your question's title and content do not match up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, `"mm-yyyy"` is not a date.  If you just want a value for printing/plotting, just format the Date column via `format(df$Date, "%m-%Y")`.  If you want to use the result as a measure of time, use `zoo::as.yearmon`.